# Error! 401.shtml file not found, what's the problem?

Tags: errors

There's a file missing in errors log in cpanel I can see the following error:

```
2020-08-22 12:44:37.659980 [INFO] [13028] [172.68.24.86:13002#APVH_click.af:443] File not found [/home/clickaf/public_html/401.shtml]
```

Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Your time may be better served procuring services via Upwork or Freelancer.com. Run tests using gmetrix.com and google pagespeed insights, post those to your job postings, and determine who can do the most for you. Good luck.